# How to filter dataset in R and use a function on the filtered dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

How do I filter data based on some condition, and then run a function on the filtered dataset.

For example: Say I’m looking at the titanic dataset

```
library(titanic)
library(epitools)
```

and I want to look at risk ratios of males compared to females of surviving. But I only want to look at males and females over the age of 20.

I know I can do it like this

```
titanic_filtered <- titanic %>% filter(age >= 20)

riskratio(table(titanic_filtered$Sex, titanic_filtered$Survived))
```

However I don’t want to have create a filtered dataset every time. Is there a way to do this in one line?

So ideally it would be something like

```
titanic %>% filter(age >= 20) %>% riskratio(table(titanic$Sex, titanic$Survived))
```

However this wouldn’t work as it wouldn’t use the filtered dataset. Is there a way to do this in one line without saving the filtered dataset to a new name and using that?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: When I do run it by replacing titanic with "." I just get this error: Error in nrow(x) : object 'x' not found

Comment: titanic %>% filter(Age >= 30) %>% riskratio(table(.$Sex, .$Survived)) is specifically what I ran

Comment: Since my "." idea was a flop, a different idea, maybe something like riskratio(table(titanic %>% filter(age >= 20) %>%select(Sex, Survived)))

Comment: Shouldn't just piping it together like `titanic %>% filter(age >= 20) %>% select(Sex, Survived) %>% table() %>% riskratio()` work?